# Why does my Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc LT15a reboot itself and not even load the home screen?

Tags: backup, boot-loop, sony-xperia-arc

I have Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc LT15a and suddenly the phone started to reboot itself. I'm assuming it's the memory is too low to load the OS main screen. Now, I have important data on the phone internal memory under the app called NoteEverything and I'm desperately trying to retrieve it somehow. Is there a way to start up the Xperia Arc in safe mode and delete some apps to free up memory? OR should I open the phone and disconnect some hardware maybe this will free up memory? How can I copy the ROM info which is the internal memory of the phone to another device or extra storage?

What should I do, what do you suggest? I am willing to do the impossible to have it up and running so at least I get my data backup!

p.s., I don't want to use the PC companion and delete my internal ROM coz it will delete everything and I don’t want this in the first place.

Comment: I'm a little shocked that the app doesn't have a built-in way to back up its data.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this device. Does it have an SD card? Were you storing your data there? If so, you can probably drop that into a SD card reader (or another phone) and pull the data off that way.

Comment: @user267 NoteEverything *has* backup functionality included, and does backups to SDCard. At least with the Pro version. As I went straight to buy it, I cannot speak for the free version.

Comment: @Sam Did you try the safe-mode? It is available for your device (just google it: hard to find how to enter it, most people are concerned to get out again): when booting, simply hold *the left and right button below the screen and press on until it loaded.* ([source](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20666/16575))

Answer (score -3):

Try:

- Removing SIM
- Restart phone then go to setting -wireless networks-more-mobile n/w-n/w operator
- Here you select search mode manual then select your network in 2G mode(ex. Vodaphone 2g or Airtel2g etc). Make sure not to select a 3G network.

Comment: Please, use proper spelling. It improves the readability of your answer.